# How to change PaxExam port

Tags: jetty, cxf, port, apache-karaf, pax-exam

I have a successfully running suite of integration tests using PaxExam. I run the tests using Maven. The purpose of the tests is to test REST web services implemented through Apache CXF running in Karaf.

The tests run on my machine but fail during Jenkins build due to port conflict. The CXF uses port 8181 which seems to be the default Jetty port. Is there a way to change this port declaratively or programmatically in the tests suite?

I tried using a variety of PaxExam options listed here:

http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXEXAM3/Configuration+Options, but to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Pax-Exam-Karaf or do you use plain Pax-Exam, 
if it's Pax-Exam-Karaf use the following for your configuration:

```
KarafDistributionOption.editConfigurationFilePut("etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg",
 "org.osgi.service.http.port", "alternative-port"),
```

if it's plain Pax-Exam:

```
systemProperty("org.osgi.service.http.port").value("8181")
```

You might also take a look on how Karaf does it's regression testing at [Karaf Regression Test](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/trunk/tooling/exam/regression/src/test/java/org/apache/karaf/tooling/exam/regression/KarafWithBundleTest.java) or take a look at the pax-web itests at [Pax-Web Integration Tests](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/itest/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/ITestBase.java)

Comment: Achim, thank you for your reply. Indeed using the first option solved the CXF port conflict. I am still getting this message (although it does not seem to affect the test performance):

2013-02-28 09:35:04,838 | WARN  | ion(3)-127.0.0.1 | NIOSocketConnectorWrapper        | ternal.NIOSocketConnectorWrapper   45 | 99 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 1.1.3 | Connection on port 8080 cannot be open. Exception:java.net.BindException: Address already in use Reason: Address already in use

Any idea how to change port 8080 used by Jetty?

Comment: depends on which version of Karaf/Pax-Web you're using if it's a 2.2.x version of Karaf just ignore it since this is due to the fact that the  jetty.xml in the ect folder of karaf is also interpreted and this one ususally tries to use the 8080 port first. It's the way the jetty server is used, at first the jetty server needs to be started, and after that it's configured to use the right ports. That's probably the main reason for this. As I said, try to ignore it :-)